# how can I improve my Codeigniter code?

Tags: codeigniter

The code that i post bellow works just fine, and the page is displayed properly.

Controller:

```
class Articles extends Frontend_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->homeMetaTags = $this->configOptionsModel->get(1);
        $this->bgimage = $this->configOptionsModel->get(2);
        $this->db->where('catid = "1"');
        $this->services = $this->articlesModel->get();
        $this->projects = $this->projectsModel->get();
    }

    public function displayArticle()
{

        $data['default_metatags'] = $this->homeMetaTags;
        $data['bgimage'] = $this->bgimage;
        $data['services'] = $this->services;
        $data['projects'] = $this->projects;
        $this->load->model('articlesModel');
        $artid = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->db->where('artid ='.$artid);
        $data['article'] = $this->articlesModel->get();
        $data['main_content'] = 'articles';
        $this->load->model('articlesImagesModel');
        $this->db->where('artid ='.$artid);
        $data['artimg'] = $this->articlesImagesModel->get();
    $this->load->view('frontEnd/template',$data);       
}
}
```

View:

```
<?php echo $article[0]['title'];?>
<?php echo $article[0]['articletext'];?>
```

In the address bar the following url is displayed:

www.mysite.com/articles/displayArticle/3
So far, so good.

But... If i type in the address bar: www.mysite.com/articles/displayArticle/3546666

Instead to be redirected to the custom 404 error page,  I get the following errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 0
Filename: frontEnd/articles.php
Line Number: 12

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 0
Filename: frontEnd/articles.php
Line Number: 48
```

Sure enough those  lines 12 and 48 are the two lines where the code from the view are located.

I would like if someone type non existing id to be redirected to the 404 page instead of seeing those errors.Anyone can help?

Regards,Zoran

Comment: post your model code there is some problem with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Articles extends Frontend_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->homeMetaTags     =   $this->configOptionsModel->get(1);
        $this->bgimage          =   $this->configOptionsModel->get(2);
        $this->db->where('catid',1);// What is this doing here. This should be in model
        $this->services         =   $this->articlesModel->get();
        $this->projects         =   $this->projectsModel->get();
    }

    public function displayArticle()
    {
        $this->load->model('articlesModel');
        $this->load->model('articlesImagesModel');

        $data['default_metatags']   =   $this->homeMetaTags;
        $data['bgimage']            =   $this->bgimage;
        $data['services']           =   $this->services;
        $data['projects']           =   $this->projects;

        $artid = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $this->db->where('artid',$artid);// What is this doing here. This should be in model

        $data['article']            =   $this->articlesModel->get();
        $data['main_content']       =   'articles';
        /*  What is it doing here */
        $this->db->where('artid ='.$artid);

        $data['artimg']             =   $this->articlesImagesModel->get();

        $this->load->view('frontEnd/template',$data);       
    }
}
```

I assume when you are calling `$this->articlesModel->get()` you are returning 
`row_array()` instead of `result_array()`. The function is returning object not 
array of objects. Change in your model `row_array()` to `result_array()` or in view

```
<?php echo $article['title'];?>
<?php echo $article['articletext'];?>
```

This should work fine

Comment: indeed, has this in my model: $method = $single ? 'row_array' : 'result_array';

Answer (score 0):

Try to properly use the View Model Controller models.
Currently you are retrieving database access in your controller. I suggest you watch this to get started.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWsAruzW3Jw

Anyway, to show a 404 page use this:

```
show_404();
```

404 handler:

```
 /**
* 404 Page Handler
*
* This function is similar to the show_error() function above
* However, instead of the standard error template it displays
* 404 errors.
*
* @access public
* @return void
*/
 function show_404($page = '', $log_error = TRUE)
 {
  $_error =& load_class('Exceptions', 'core');
  $_error->show_404($page, $log_error);
  exit;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You must re-factor your code. Model code shouldn't mess with controller like (get, where functions). you should handle this in model itself by passing some values.

2) in the this line '$this->db->where('artid ='.$artid);' you should validate the $artid before passing in this function.

3) Use try catch statement to show the 404 page if you got error message like this.

4) If you are redirecting to 404 page, you should log the errors properly to fix it later.

5) If you need to common functionality, keep it in the helpers and call the function name. Don't keep the whole code in the construct function. This is the best practice.

If you need anything else, ask me. Thanks. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi Sakthi...can you post any example (code snippet) of validating the id?

Comment: Sure. Here, you can validate ctype_digit(). Please check the codeignitor helper libraries. I don't remember in the codignitor. Long time no touch.